# The given key was not present in the dictionary - MS CRM FetchXML

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

HUGE EDIT:

It seems through trying to make things simple to show the issue I was making it more complicated.

Here is the full function in action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getCPDActiviesByMemberNumber(int memberNumber) {

List<Entity> sourceData = null;
List<CPDActivity> membersActivites = new List<CPDActivity>();
List<member> memberRecords = new List<member>();

try {

    string xmlFile = "";
    string memberNumberString = memberNumber.ToString();
    xmlFile = File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"_Code\Fetch\MembersActivities.xml");
    xmlFile = String.Format(xmlFile, memberNumberString);
    OrganizationServiceClient crm = new OrganizationServiceClient();
    sourceData = crm.GetEntities(xmlFile);

    if (sourceData.Count > 0) {

        member member = new member();

        foreach (Entity entity in sourceData) {

            CPDActivity cpdActivity = new CPDActivity();

            // sb_membership
            member.ID = entity.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("sb_membershipid");
            member.MemberNumber = entity.GetAttributeValue<String>("sb_membershipno");
            member.ContactID = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("sb_contactid").Id.ToString(); ;
            member.MembershipStatus = entity.FormattedValues["statuscode"].ToString();
            member.MemberGrade = entity.GetAttributeValue<String>("sb_name");
            member.StartDate = entity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("sb_startdate").ToString();
            member.ExpiryDate = entity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("sb_expirydate").ToString();
            // contact (membercontact)
            member.Title = entity.FormattedValues["membercontact.sb_title"].ToString();
            member.FirstName = entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("membercontact.firstname").Value.ToString();
            member.LastName = entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("membercontact.lastname").Value.ToString();
            member.RegionCode = entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("membercontact.sb_regioncode").Value.ToString();
            member.Email = entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("membercontact.emailaddress1").Value.ToString();
            // contact (membercontact) - sb_cpdactivity (cpdactivity) 
            member.Region = entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("region.sb_name").Value.ToString();
            // sb_cpdactivity (cpdactivity)
            cpdActivity.ActivityName = entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("cpdactivity.sb_name").Value.ToString();
            cpdActivity.CreatedOn = (DateTime)entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("cpdactivity.createdon").Value;
            cpdActivity.CpdHours = Convert.ToSingle(entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("cpdactivity.sb_cpdhours").Value);
            cpdActivity.ActivityDate = (DateTime)entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("cpdactivity.sb_activitydate").Value;
            cpdActivity.StatusCode = entity.FormattedValues["cpdactivity.statuscode"].ToString();
            cpdActivity.CpdActivityID = (Guid)entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("cpdactivity.sb_cpdactivityid").Value;
            cpdActivity.MemberContactID = ((EntityReference)entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("cpdactivity.sb_membercontactid").Value).Id;
            //
            cpdActivity.EventType = entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("cpdactivity.sb_type").Value.ToString();  // <<<<< problem here
            cpdActivity.EventType = entity.FormattedValues["cpdactivity.sb_type"].ToString();  // <<<<< problem here
            //
            member.Activities.Add(cpdActivity);
            memberRecords.Add(member);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, memberRecords);

    } else {

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "getCPDActiviesByMemberId " + "no records found");

    }

} catch (Exception ex) {

    string error = ex.Message.ToString();
    string errors = error;
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "getMembers - error : " + error);

}

}
```

And here is the FetchXML:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="sb_membership">
    <attribute name="sb_contactid" />
    <attribute name="sb_name" />
    <attribute name="sb_membershipno" />
    <attribute name="sb_expirydate" />
    <attribute name="sb_startdate" />
    <attribute name="statuscode" />
    <attribute name="sb_membershipid" />
    <order attribute="sb_name" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
      <condition attribute="sb_membershipno" operator="eq" value='{0}' />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="sb_contactid" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="membercontact">
      <attribute name="sb_title" />
      <attribute name="lastname" />
      <attribute name="firstname" />
      <attribute name="mobilephone" />
      <attribute name="emailaddress1" />
      <attribute name="sb_regioncode" />
      <link-entity name="sb_geographicregion" from="sb_regioncode" to="sb_regioncode" link-type="outer" alias="region">
        <attribute name="sb_name" />
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
    <link-entity name="sb_cpdactivity" from="sb_membercontactid" to="sb_contactid" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="cpdactivity">
      <attribute name="sb_cpdactivityid" />
      <attribute name="sb_membercontactid" />
      <attribute name="sb_name" />
      <attribute name="sb_type" />
      <attribute name="createdon" />
      <attribute name="sb_activitydate" />
      <attribute name="statuscode" />
      <attribute name="sb_cpdhours" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

The problem is when trying to get to the sb_type (note not eventdateid as mentioned previously) attribute (a column which does appear in the database) I get the error "The given key was not present in the dictionary."  So the column DOES appear in the database table and is referenced in the fetchXML exactly as it is in the database but when looking at the entity while debugging the attribute is not listed unlike others in the fetchXML such as 'sb_name'.

Comment: What happens when you also include the id attribute in the fetchxml? Does this also happen for other entities? What code are you using to execute the fetch xml?

Comment: What happens if you use distinct="true"

Comment: @user1515791 Code edited.  If I include the id in the fetchXML nothing changes, I still only get one attribute back (sb_cpdactivityid) and the same error

Comment: Please can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), clearly showing where the exception occurs. It's not clear from question.

Comment: I use a OrganizationServiceProxy instance with 
                    RetrieveMultipleRequest fetchRequest1 = new RetrieveMultipleRequest
                    {
                        Query = new FetchExpression(xml)
                    };

                    EntityCollection returnCollection = ((RetrieveMultipleResponse)_service.Execute(fetchRequest1)).EntityCollection; So, that might be different..

Comment: @JamesWood I have removed the trimmed-down example and placed the actual function and fetchXML being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior of FetchXML query. When your resultset is going to have `NULL` value in a column (attribute) for all the records, then that attribute will not be included in `EntityCollection` resultset.

If atleast one record is having value for that column, then the resultset will include that column.

Do a check like this & continue.

```
var thing;
if(entity.Contains("sb_eventdateid")){
    thing = entity.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("sb_eventdateid");
}
```

**Update**:
It’s best practice to handle the `null` check like below when you are getting `null` columns - before accessing `.Value`

```
if(entity.Attributes.Contains("cpdactivity.sb_type") && entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("cpdactivity.sb_type") != null)
{
            cpdActivity.EventType = entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("cpdactivity.sb_type").Value.ToString();  
            cpdActivity.EventType = entity.FormattedValues["cpdactivity.sb_type"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: There is no real need for the `contains` and `GetAttributeValue` check. `GetAttributeValue` will return `null` or `default(type)` (in this case `Guid.Empty`).  `GetAttributeValue` [method will return null or the default value for the type rather than throw an exception.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg326129.aspx)

Comment: I have noticed this problem only occures when a record has at least 1 NULL value in one of the columns.  How do I allow for NULL values when then occur in the database?

Comment: @ArunVinoth I have made the change you suggested and although it looks like it should make sense the error still occurs as soon as 'if(entity.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("cpdactivity.sb_type") != null)' is hit.  It's like sb_type no longer exists in the fetchXML.

Comment: @Ryan see my updated answer. I have added another check in addition to && operator

Comment: @ArunVinoth That works, thanks.  Was looking for a way of handling columns that may have nulls and this does the trick.  Is it best practice to run this check on EVERY attribute?